# Proving $A$ is similar to $B$ when $\operatorname{adj} A$ is similar to $\operatorname{adj} B$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A,B$ are two $6 \times 6$ real matrices and $A$ is invertible. I need to prove that if $\operatorname{adj} A$ is similar to $\operatorname{adj} B$ then $A$ is similar to $B$.

$\operatorname{adj}A = M^{-1}(\operatorname{adj}B) M$ but can't think of a direction to the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use the relations
\begin{align}
A\operatorname{adj}A&=\det(A)I,\tag{1}\\
B\operatorname{adj}B&=\det(B)I\tag{2}
\end{align}
to prove first that $\det A=\det B$.

One way to do that: prove that
$$
\det A\ne 0\implies \det\operatorname{adj}A\ne 0\implies 
\det\operatorname{adj}B\ne 0\implies \det B\ne 0.
$$
Then take the determinant of boths side in (1) and (2).

Comment: thanks!! yet I still couldn't understand what am I missing. I defined $\ \operatorname{adj}A = A^{-1} |A| I $ and the same with B and from the details of the question $\ \operatorname{adj}A = P^{-1} \cdot \operatorname{adj}B \cdot P $ so its just $\ A^{-1} \cdot |A| \cdot I = P^{-1} \cdot B^{-1} \cdot |B| \cdot I \cdot P $ and can't get any further from here.. Oh and btw, why would proving detA = det B would help me? I mean two matrices could have the same determinant & trace & rank and yet not be similar.. correct?

Comment: @bm1125 You cannot use $B^{-1}$ until you prove it exists, e.g. prove that $\det B\ne 0$. Once you prove the determinants are equal, the rest is quite simple algebra calculation from the same relations and similarity of $\operatorname{adj}A$ and $\operatorname{adj}B$.

Comment: right! thanks again. So $\ det(\operatorname{adj}A) = det(A)^{n-1} = det(A)^5 $ and so $\ det(\operatorname{adj}B) = det(\operatorname{adj}A $ because they are similar and thus $\ det(B) \not = 0 $ and $\ B$ is invertible. I'm not sure how to find invertible matrix such that $\ A = P^{-1} B P $ ??

Comment: @bm1125 You can e.g. continue from what you wrote above $$ A^{-1} \cdot |A| \cdot I = P^{-1} \cdot B^{-1} \cdot |B| \cdot I \cdot P$$ Cancel the deteminants (equal) and take the inverse of each side.

Comment: Ahh cool, so from $\ A^{-1} = P^{-1} \ cdot B^{-1} \cdot P $ I can conclude that A and B are similar? Thanks a lot for your patience! you really helped me!

Comment: @bm1125 Yes, because then $$A=(A^{-1})^{-1}=(P^{-1}B^{-1}P)^{-1}=P^{-1}BP.$$